# How can we call a function mutable for self inside a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, rust, ownership

When iterating a field from a structure, the `for` loop borrows the ownership on `self` if I understood correctly.
This is annoying if one needs to call methods that mutate `self.`

This is distinct from [How to run for loop on elements of a vector and change the vector inside the for loop and outside the for loop in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57637354/how-to-run-for-loop-on-elements-of-a-vector-and-change-the-vector-inside-the-for) as I do not try to modify any element from the iterated set.

For instance, this code: ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=7b8171af9e4957aa43437a73e9b9540f))

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct MyStruct {
    myset: HashMap<String,u8>,
    x: usize,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new(x: usize) -> MyStruct {
        MyStruct {
            myset: HashMap::new(),
            x: x, 
        }
    }
    
    fn fill(&mut self){
        self.myset.insert("John".to_string(), 12);
    }
    
    
    fn mutable_x_only(&mut self){
        self.x = 4;
    }
    
    fn try_iteration(&mut self){
        self.mutable_x_only(); // does work
        for (_name, _age) in &self.myset{ // this for loop borrows the `self`ownership
            self.mutable_x_only(); // does not work: self is not mutable here
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut my_struct_set = MyStruct::new(42);
    my_struct_set.fill();
    my_struct_set.try_iteration();
}
```

Generates this error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:28:13
   |
27 |         for (_name, _age) in &self.myset{ // this for loop borrows the `self`ownership
   |                              -----------
   |                              |
   |                              immutable borrow occurs here
   |                              immutable borrow later used here
28 |             self.mutable_x_only(); // does not work: self is not mutable here
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

From my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68981252/rust-borrow-immutable-error-e0502-with-a-hashset-example), I understood that the ownership is taken by the for loop, but it appears that `self` itself is borrowed.

Comment: *that the ownership is taken by the for loop* — yes, ownership **of the reference** is taken: `&self.myset`. *if this function does not try to mutate `myset`* — **prove** that to the compiler. The signature of `mutable_function` allows for it to mutate `myset` (even if you currently are not). Change the signature such that it's statically impossible for that to be the case.

Comment: @Shepmaster I have reformulated and simplified my question with respect to your feedbacks. Thanks !